# Follow redirect of a captive portal with NodeMCU 0.9

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu, http

## What am I doing?

Trying to connect to a free wifi with a Nodemcu 0.9.

## What I have already done?

Connecting and loading a test page in order to be redirected to the login page

**Connection code:**

```
 const char* ssid = "polimi";

  Serial.println("Attempting to connect");
  WiFi.begin(ssid);
  //Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
```

**Detection of captive portal**

```
  String host = "clients3.google.com";
  String site = "/generate_204";

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  // We now create a URI for the request
  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(site);

  client.print(String("GET ") + site + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
    "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
    "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");  
  delay(500);

  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }
  Serial.println("");

  Serial.println("###Connection closed###");
```

## What am I obtaining?

Nothing, but I wanted to obtain the html strings of the captive portal

## What I'd Like

Find a way to follow the redirect and finally send a POST with my credential.

Comment: nothing? it connects to wifi? it connects to server? maybe it takes longer then 500 ms until the response arrives

Comment: @Juraj For sure it connects to the wifi then print the "requesting url..." and "###connection close ###". Absolutely no redirect. Client. Readstring does nothing

Comment: your way of waiting for the response with delay is wrong. see some WiFiClient example

Comment: @Juraj Can you show me where to find interesting example? This is what I've found on internet. I suppose I'm waiting using: `while(client.available())`. If I am writing here is because I don't understand where's the error

Comment: now I see that the esp8266 library has not so good example. try to adopt AVR WiFi Shield library example or this example https://github.com/jandrassy/UnoWiFiDevEdSerial1/blob/master/examples/WiFiLinkWebClient/WiFiLinkWebClient.ino

Comment: use the httpclient instead of the low-level stuff to make it easier on yourself.

Comment: @dandavis Is there any working httpclient?

Comment: So far I was able to import `RestClient.h` that allows me to send a POST request, now it will be quite hard to read a possible redirect

Comment: there's a few built-in "ESP8266HttpClient" example, which use a high-level interface.